# How to change the content coming from a post regularly after a certain interval of time?

Tags: wordpress

> Here Testimonials is the title for the post coming from wordpress and
>   the rest is body of the post coming from wordpress on the site. I want
>   to change the content on a regular interaval while the title should
>   remain fixed on the site. What should I do?

```
TESTIMONIALS


    Gratusglobal1

    With customer satisfaction as our main focus, we will be the best fit for your support                             requirements. form gratus technology
```

Comment: You need to explain a bit first that are you looking for updated content of same post (which is a bit odd as why would you update same testimonial again & again) or are you looking to replace this testimonial with another one like a slider.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax functions with `setTimeinterval` of javascript.

For example, if using jQuery:

```
setTimeinterval(function(){

   $('#div1').load('<URL HERE>'); // div1 is ID of Div in which you want to replace the content

}, 20000); // after 20 seconds
```